# Classe não registrada - Imagelist

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Ao personalizar a minha imagelist e listview aparece o seguinte erro:

> Classe não Registrada. Procurando Objeto com CLSID:{7EBDAAE0-8120-11CF-899F-00AA00688B10}

Acredito que seja porque meu Office é 64bits, alguém com Office 64 bits já conseguiu contornar uma situação semelhante?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que pesquisei dizem que é necessário registar o

> Msstkprp.dll file.

Vê algumas dicas neste link http://www.visualbasicsource.net/KnowledgeBase/q188331.txt